# Spring data Mongodb declaring String type datetime in mongo repository.java

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am converting mongo string column to datetime. If I declare it as a string in `mongorepository` and call it as a date in `command.java`. it is throwing error.

```
public interface RatingResponseRepository extends MongoRepository
List<collection> findByserviceRequestedTimestampBetween(String startDate,String endDate);
```

Command.java

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd h:m");
    List<RatingTiming> response = repo.findByserviceRequestedTimestampBetween(sdf.parse(query.getStartvalue()), sdf.parse(query.getEndvalue()));
```

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Error :The method findByserviceRequestedTimestampBetween(String, String) in the type RatingResponseRepository is not applicable for the arguments (Date, Date). Source is string, so I had it as string on repository.java.

Comment: is anyone familiar with string to datetime conversion in extends MongoRepository.java